VSCode, Flutter: Try-Catch block doesn't catch Exception
I'm trying to catch an exception that occurs in my code line
var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
but the error is not caught.
The compiler stops at the line and shows:
Exception:
StateError (Bad state: No element)

If I skip a few exceptions in this place, the code will execute correctly(I mean nothing was caught). There will be no errors in the console, only "Excel decoding successful" print and the excel file is imported correctly.
Code:
 void readFile(File file) {
    log('Excel Data Import In Process...');
    var bytes = File(file.path).readAsBytesSync();
    try {
      print('Excel Import in process');
      var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes); // exception in this line ...
      print('Excel decoding successful'); // ... but still successful
      //rest of code
    } on StateError catch (e) {
      print('StateError Excel: $e');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Exception Excel: $e');
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('Error Excel: $e');
      print('Stack $stackTrace');
    }
}

Stack & Variables
I tried:

using another excel file (error occurred);
using an empty excel file (error occurred);
using the file directly, not through the file picker (error occurred),
running this code in a new flutter project (no error occurred)
when running the application in profile mode on a real device(no error occurred).


The decodeBytes method is not throwing probably.
Here is an example, how it can be handled.
Excel parseExcelFile(List<int> _bytes) {
  return Excel.decodeBytes(_bytes);
}

and then
Excel excel = await compute(parseExcelFile, _bytes);


Didn't work for me. Exception still occur
